# Display x input textbox based ont the value of a combobox (asp/vbscript)

Tags: forms, list, vbscript, asp-classic

Dears,

I am trying to display a number of textbox based on the value selected in a slection list.

The selection list corresponds to the number of children (0,1,2,3...). For example, if i select 2, 2 textbox should appear and so on.

Here is a preview of the code :

```
     <script>
          function GetSelectedTextValue(obj) {
            var selectedText = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
            var selectedValue = obj.value;
            alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
          }
      </script>

     Select the number of child : <select id="nb_kids" name="nb_kids" style="background: #a2c8c8;" onChange="GetSelectedTextValue(this);" size="1">
       <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>

            <br/><br/>
<%
'nb = 10
'while i <= nb
'if i <> 0 then
'Response.Write("Child" & i & "<input type=text name=nom size=25 required> <BR>")
'end if
'i = i+1
'wend
     %>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This seems to be asp classic, not asp.net...

Comment: it's better to use javascript in this case to dynamically generating the textbox otherwise you have to do a entire server side postback in asp every time the dropdown changes which can be slow

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes It's a classic asp. Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes It's a classic asp. Do you know how to do it in JS because I have no expertise in it.